# How to choose the suggestion from suggestion list

Tags: vim

I'm using `neocomplete` plugin for vim.
I can't figure out how to choose the suggestion from the list.

[image]

What is the meaning of letters [B] and [S]?
How I can use them to select suggestion?

Comment: This is a good indication that the documentation in neocomplete is really poor.  It's only deals with installation :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those letters are only there to show you additional information about the item on the left; they can't be used for selection. See `:help neocomplete` for an explanation.

You navigate the default completion menu with `<Down>` and `<Up>` and select the highlighted item with `<C-y>`. See `:help popupmenu-keys`. Again, read your plugin's documentation to see if it deviates from the default in any way.